# How is AWS Cognito secure?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I tried to integrate AWS cognito user pool, However I feel like it's not secure any more. Because id token receives in login contains the user pool id. Using that user pool id any one can access user detail list.

Example - Below shows my id_token data and there I can clearly see my user pool id in iss field (us-east-1_i1SXXXXX)

[image]

So using that user pool id, I can retrieve list users and then edit any user details.

Retrieve user details -

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
    var util = require('util');

    var params = {
        Username: '',
        Password: '',
        UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_i1SGXXXXX', // just paste id token user pool
        ClientId: 'ZZZZZZZZZZ', // just random string
        AWSRegion: 'us-east-1' //region
    }

    AWS.config.update({region: params.AWSRegion});

    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : params.UserPoolId,
        ClientId : params.ClientId
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData);


    var userData = {
        Username : params.Username,
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoUser(userData);

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers({UserPoolId: params.UserPoolId}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
         console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
                  console.log(data.Users);
        }
      });
```

Finally you can edit user details -

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
var util = require('util');

global.navigator = () => null;

var params = {
    Username: '',
    Password: '',
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_i1SGXXXXX',
    ClientId: '',
    IdentityPoolId: '',
    AWSRegion: 'us-east-1'
}
AWS.config.update({
    region: params.AWSRegion
});
var authenticationData = {
    Username: params.Username,
    Password: params.Password
};
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var params = {
    UserAttributes: [{
            Name: 'address',
            Value: 'address updated'
        }
    ],
    UserPoolId: params.UserPoolId,
    /* required */
    Username: 'XXXXXXX' //add any user id where you retrieve from list of user code
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

So what is your suggestion. Am I doing anything wrong in creating idToken?

Comment: Where are you running this example code?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `id` of the `userpool` you cannot just "ask" Cognito on user details because:

The access on the userpools are governed by AWS' IAM (given by you/admin), so perhaps you have no authentication
enforcement on the userpool through IAM?! I highly doubt it.

Obviously, if my web written web app has access to the userpool, then I can ask to do what it 
wants to do with the user pool.

Moreover, what is your app setting within the user pool?

Comment: Just run my first code by replacing user pool id then you will see. Further check this link too - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property (only user pool id is required, according to this)

Comment: What is your IAM setting for the user pool?

Comment: App setting within the user pool is Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH). There is nothing to do with IAM settings

Comment: var params = {
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  AttributesToGet: [
    'STRING_VALUE',
    /* more items */
  ],
  Filter: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Limit: 0,
  PaginationToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
}); There aws cognito requires only user pool id nothing else

Answer (score 0):

In case this question is still relevant, did you happen to execute the code on a machine that implicitly get Cognito admin permissions? For instance, if it was run on your laptop, did your laptop have the `.aws` directory that contains a `credentials` file? If it was run as a Lambda function, was the Lambda function granted a role that has Cognito admin permissions?